# Cpanel Java Email Client Program

Tags: java, email, smtp, cpanel

If anyone tried/found working java email/smtp/imap client program that connects to cPanel's email a/cs and send emails out then please share it.  It has been a tiresome efforts in trying to find that code online but none of them works fine.  I did try more than five varieties of code but nothing worked.  Below are few samples:

### Sample# 1

```
    String host = "mail.domain.net"; 
String user = "catch-all@domain.net";
String pass = "xxxx";
String to = "admin@domain.net";
String from = "catch-all@domain.net";
String subject = "Dummy subject";
String messageText = "Dummy body";
boolean sessionDebug = false;
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.host", host);
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", 2525); //25 - default

Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);
Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
try {
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    msg.setText(messageText);
    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(host, user, pass);
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

### Error

```
Sending mail..  Done!javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.dealstock.net, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1706)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:525)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:192)
    at com.mail.EmailsSender2.main(EmailsSender2.java:209)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:432)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:284)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:227)
    at com.sun.mai
```

From the Cpanel account, the designated port is 2525, if secured then 465, but none of the ports work.  With post 2525, it does connects, but there is no response and waits for 1-2 minitues and then timeouts.  If I change to port 25, then it simply throws above error.  With same Cpanel email a/c my another program able to connect and read emails through POP, but failing with sending emails.

Appreciate if you can share your comments/inputs.

Comment: so the error above is correct for port 25 isn't it.  Change it to port 2525 and debug from there.

Comment: I did try with 2525, but no response and timesout after sometime.

Answer (score 2):

I have hostgator, and when creating session, use the following code it works (with no encryption or SSL, not TLS).

btw, port 25 is blocked by my isp (Verizon), and hostgator has it on port 26, not 2525. make sure your hosting company has it running on 2525.

```
    private Session getSession(final EmailConfig emailConfig) {
    String port = Integer.toString(emailConfig.getPort());
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", emailConfig.getHost());
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

    if (Encryption.SSL == emailConfig.getEncryption()) {
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    }
    else if (Encryption.TLS == emailConfig.getEncryption()) {
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    }

    return Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(emailConfig.getUsername(), emailConfig.getDecryptedPassword());
        }
    });
}


    private void sendMessage(Session session, InternetAddress from, InternetAddress[] to, InternetAddress[] cc, 
        InternetAddress[] bcc, String subject, String text) throws AuthenticationFailedException {
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        message.setFrom(from);
        if (to != null) {
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
        }
        if (cc != null) {
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, cc);
        }
        if (bcc != null) {
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, bcc);
        }
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(text);

        Transport.send(message);
    }
    catch (AuthenticationFailedException ex) {
        log.info("authentication failed", ex);
        throw ex;
    }
    catch (MessagingException e) {
        log.info("error sending message", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks allot Anthony, for your comments and code.  It is working fine.  Also, just few days ago I found the same port 2525 working on the same server.  Now, everything is setttled :-)

Comment: This worked like a charm. The two critical required properties are "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port" and "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class". Even in the docs for my own cPanel this is not clear, and the settings for SSL/TLS are combined as if they are identical. As least with a Java transport client, you need to use the correct one, as is very clear in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

This would definitely work for you.

Just call this function to send automated email to client. 
In parameter "to" is email address to which you want to send an email.

I usually do it in Maven project. If you are using maven project then import following dependencies.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4

```
    final String username = "youremail@gmail.com";
    final String password = "yourpassword";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("youremail@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(emailBody, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Comment: This answer is good as far as it goes, but is missing the two critical properties required for cPanel implementations: "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port" and "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class". These are covered in the answer from [Anthony Ho](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17089822/2657515)